# Android: problems with getSelectedItem on a spinner

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, spinner, getselection

I have  a `Spinner`, and put the selected item in the body of a mail.
this is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_modulo);

    Spinner spinnerTaglia = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTaglia);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,     R.array.Taglie, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerTaglia.setPrompt("Seleziona la taglia!");

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinnerTaglia.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
            adapter,
            R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
            // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional
            this));

    final String taglia = spinnerTaglia.getSelectedItem().toString();


    Button btnCompilaOrdine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCompilaOrdine);
    btnCompilaOrdine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"MAIL@gmail.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MAIL OBJECT");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Taglia: "+taglia);
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Modulo.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
    });
}
```

The application start correctly in the emulator and the debugger show me nothing (I'm using Android Studio) but when i click on the button that take me in this activity the application crash and the Android Studio's Debugger show me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the row:

final String taglia = spinnerTaglia.getSelectedItem().toString();

how can i fix this?

Comment: it looks like no item is selected, so getSelectedItem() returns null. shouldn't you add a onSelection callback or something like this?

Answer (score 3):

`getSelectedItem()` returns null if there is nothing selected on your spinner and calling `toString()` is making your application crash. Get rid of

```
final String taglia = spinnerTaglia.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

and in your onClick do:

```
if (spinnerTaglia.getSelectedItem() == null) {
      return;
}
String taglia = spinnerTaglia.getSelectedItem().toString();
// the other code
```

Comment: Ok, with this implementation at click on button the module with the spinner open correctly, but now it show me another error after the spinner's choice, when i click on the button btnCompilaOrdine:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method compilaOrdine(View) in the activity class com.example.valeria.flexibilaapp.Modulo for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintButton with id 'btnCompilaOrdine'

Comment: You can either add a `public void btnCompilaOrdine(View view) {}` method in your Activity `Modulo`, or  open the layout you are using in your Activity `Modulo`, look for the `onClick` property and get rid of it

Comment: I don't remember for what reason, but i had put
android:onClick="compilaOrdine"
in the XML attribute of the button. I have cancelled it but now at click on button nothing happens!

Comment: there isn't a real reason. It another way to set an onClickListener for that view. You can do it either through the xml or programmatically calling setOnClickListener

Comment: So, the java code:
 Button btnCompilaOrdine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCompilaOrdine); btnCompilaOrdine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ public void onClick(View arg0) { 
}
can be replaced by XML attribute 
android:onclick="compilaOrdine
, right? So, if i delete the XML attribute it must work?

Comment: The xml button is:    
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Compila l'ordine"
        android:id="@+id/btnCompilaOrdine"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
and the java code is the one you see in the original question. Now when i click on the button nothing happens!

Comment: wait, chill out. Help me understand what's going on. Did you still have `btnCompilaOrdine.setOnClickListener` in your Activity ?

Comment: Yes, i have deleted android:onclic="compilaOrdine" from XML, and the java code is the same that you see above whit the add of the "if" that you have suggested.

Comment: the class you posted is called `Modulo` ?

Answer (score 1):

Move the line

```
final String taglia = spinnerTaglia.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

to inside your `OnClickListener`

Currently, you're trying to read the selected item before anything has been selected. You should also ensure that `getSelectedItem()` isn't returning null because, unless you enable / disable the `btnCompilaOrdine` button (when an item is selected), the user can press the button without selecting an item in the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should OnItemSelectedListener inseatead of a button.
[Android Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Item is returned with `NULL` value try to `Invoking the method from a null object`.

The`NullPointerException` is a `RuntimeException` and thus, the Javac compiler does not force you to use a try-catch block to handle it appropriately.

Hope this will help you to solve your issue.

for further reference visit the link below:-
`http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-nullpointerexception-how-to-handle-null-pointer-exception/`

Answer (score 0):

Your are getting the selected item before the actual rendering of the spinner. It depends on device to device that how fast it renders the screen.
Rather then getting the selected item in `getSelectionItem()` in the `onCreate()` method try out to do it in the `onClickListener()` of your `Button`.

```
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modulo);

        Spinner spinnerTaglia = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTaglia);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,     R.array.Taglie, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
        spinnerTaglia.setPrompt("Seleziona la taglia!");

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner 
        spinnerTaglia.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                adapter, 
                R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected,
                // R.layout.contact_spinner_nothing_selected_dropdown, // Optional 
                this));




        Button btnCompilaOrdine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCompilaOrdine);
        btnCompilaOrdine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

        //Get the Selected item from the spinner
        final String taglia = spinnerTaglia.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("message/rfc822");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"MAIL@gmail.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MAIL OBJECT");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Taglia: "+taglia);
        try { 
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(Modulo.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 

        } 
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mSpinner.setSelected(true);
```

If you implement this with your `spinner`, it will not give **null**.